# how to get Id or xpath for elements in popup window for automate in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

how to get Id or xpath for elements in popup window as we cannot inspect elements in popup window. I am trying to automate in python and trying to access elements by xpath or id but in case of authentication popup i am not able to find the id or xpath for username or password field so facing issue in automate. Can you please confirm how to handle authentication popup. As it is on https:/ protocol passing username and password with url is not working. Can you please help.

Comment: Hi Yusaf,I tried that but if I am opening the pop up link still i need to pass username and password and for that i need the xpath or id to enter username and password. Can you please help if i can get the xpath for elements on popup window.

Comment: ID and the Xpath path of the Popup window is found be inspecting it using the Developer console of the browser. Make sure that is a Javascript based popup window and not a Windows based else you will not be able to use selenium. Also provide the screenshot of the pop up window in the question. The more description you provide in the question the more easier it is for others to help you. Also go through the link [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi,In developer mode also inspect is not available for popup window,. Not getting option to attach screenshot file

Comment: If you are not able to inspect the popup window than it is not HTML/JavaScript based. It is probably Windows based. In this case you will not be able to used Selenium. You will have to use AutoIT , Robot Class.

Comment: Hi,I  tried to get windows handler using below code but only main window handler is coming no child handler coming when popup coming:

for handle in driver.window_handles: 
    if handle != main_page: 
        login_page = handle 
          
# change the control to signin page         
driver.switch_to.window(login_page)

I tried for AutoIT but using that not working in background window.It is working only for active window.

Can RobotClass work in python. As I searched RobotClass work only for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the href of element opens the pop-up window. And open a new tab like

```
body = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "t")
```

And open your pop-up link in new tab.

```
driver.get(<your_pop-up_link>)
```

If you send me the website, I can send you a working demo

Comment: Hi Yusaf,I tried that but if I am opening the pop up link still i need to pass username and password and for that i need the xpath or id to enter username and password. Can you please help if i can get the xpath for elements on popup window.

Comment: If you send me link you work on I can make a working demo

Comment: Hi Yusaf,Link only works on client vpn and will not work on direct internet. So can't share the link. can you please help me with exact steps to follow